# Struggling on IF conditions

Tags: java, jcreator

What the problem I want to ask is I cannot make the E part, but the V one is working and I tried all I could to figure it out what is going on in my logic...
Please help me out to make the 'E' works.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Service {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String service;
        float monthV, usaV, ausV, rusV, callV;
        float monthE, usaE, ausE, rusE, callE;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Which service did you use for the calls?<V - Vartec, E - Eircom> :   ");
        service = input.nextLine();

        if (service.charAt(0) != 'E')
            if (service.charAt(0) != 'V') {
                System.out.println("Thank you for your time...good bye.");
            } else {
                if (service.charAt(0) == 'V') {
                    System.out.print("\nPlease enter the total number of calls made in the month:   ");
                    monthV = input.nextFloat();

                    System.out.print("\nPlease enter the number of minutes spent calling the USA:   ");
                    usaV = input.nextFloat();
                    System.out.print("\nPlease enter the number of minutes spent calling the Australia:   ");
                    ausV = input.nextFloat();
                    System.out.print("\nPlease enter the number of minutes spent calling the Russia:   ");
                    rusV = input.nextFloat();
                    callV = ((usaV * 0.06f) + (ausV * 0.08f) + (rusV * 0.24f));
                    System.out.println("The total cost of using the Vartec service for the month is"
                            + String.format("%.2f", callV));
                } else {
                    if (service.charAt(0) == 'E') {
                        System.out.print("\nPlease enter the total number of calls made in the month:   ");
                        monthE = input.nextFloat();

                        System.out.print("\nPlease enter the number of minutes spent calling the USA:   ");
                        usaE = input.nextFloat();
                        System.out.print("\nPlease enter the number of minutes spent calling the Australia:   ");
                        ausE = input.nextFloat();
                        System.out.print("\nPlease enter the number of minutes spent calling the Russia:   ");
                        rusE = input.nextFloat();
                        callE = ((usaE * 0.19f) + (ausE * 0.85f) + (rusE * 0.92f));
                        System.out.println("The total cost of using the Vartec service for the month is"
                                + String.format("%.2f", callE));
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: I would use a switch where you have a case for 'V' and for 'E' and a default case for when another character has been entered.

Comment: You should have `{}` for every `if` statement. The logic is very unclear, the way it is currently written.

Comment: Indeed, with your current nested conditions, you end up checking `if (service.charAt(0)=='E')` inside a `if (service.charAt(0)!='E')` block. This will never be `true` .

Comment: first of all why would you do that?<><if (service.charAt(0)!='E')if (service.charAt(0)!='V')> it will never enter the second if. you are checking the same thing. yes your logic is wrong. think over it all over again.

Comment: Note: eventually create methods for each case like `doVartec(Scanner input)` and `doEircom(Scanner input)`, so the whole structure is much clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple way

```
char ch = service.charAt(0);

if (ch == 'E') {
   // do E
} else if (ch == 'V') {
    // do V
} else {
    // do neither E nor V - that is, BYE
}
```

a bit more *advanced* (easier to understand with more options):

```
char ch = service.charAt(0);

switch (ch) {
    case 'E':
    case 'e':  // also handle lowercase
        // do E
        break;
    case 'V':
    case 'v':
        // do V
        break;
    // more options if needed
    default:
        // do neither of the above
        break;
}
```

Your **problem** is doing something like

```
if (ch != 'E') {
    // something else
    if (ch == 'E') {
        // will never enter here
     }
}
```

**Note**: you can also use a switch with strings (unless using very old java version):

```
// changed to uppercase, we don't mind the case of input
switch (service.toUpperCase()) {
    case "VARTEC":
        ....
    case "EIRCOM":
        ...
    default:
        // I don't understand the user!
        ...
}
```

Comment: @Arnaud can you please give me some seconds.... [:-)  just kidding, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you refer to this if

```
if (service.charAt(0)=='E')
```

if yes, this one is never true because is nested in this one

```
if (service.charAt(0)!='E')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for nested if statements in your code at all.

A simple

```
if(service.charAt(0)=='V') {
     // First char is V
} else if (service.charAt(0)=='E') {
     // First char is E
} else {
     // First char is neither V nor E
}
```

will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

So `switch` and `else-if` approach would work and would be simple to debug and read. But to know the issue in the question asked is that:
`if (service.charAt(0) != 'E')` does not have a matching `else`.

So suppose the cases referring to the condition `if (service.charAt(0) != 'E')`:

**case 1**. When you input `V` the above condition becomes true and the flow goes in this `if` and the execution flows as expected for `V`.

**case 2**. When you input `E` , then above condition becomes false as the input is indeed `E` - so the flow does not goes in this `if` and the code written for `E` never gets executed(since its written in `if` inside which the flow does not goes),  And since we do not have any `else` part also hence the program would terminate.

So if you are inclined to use `if` only and not switch then to correct the implementation you should replace `if (service.charAt(0) != 'E')` with

```
if (service.charAt(0) != 'E' && service.charAt(0) != 'V'){
            System.out.println("Thank you for your time...good bye.");
        } else {
             ... rest of the code as usual  
        }
```